# Regex to strip a variable number of periods from username in email address?

Tags: regex, replace, mariadb

I'm cleaning up spam accounts in my forum, and found a bunch of email addresses with the following format:

```
n.fl.jersey.s@gmail.com
nfl.jerseys@gmail.com
n.flj.er.se.ys@gmail.com
```

Gmail treats these all as the same email account, versus the forum software treats them as distinct email addresses, so spammers use this trick to re-use the same email address again and again when creating spam forum accounts.

In order to identify them, I need to strip out all the periods before the `@gmail.com`. Then it's easy to identify all the duplicate accounts.

Fortunately, MariaDB 10 has a new `REGEXP_REPLACE` function designed for exactly these types of problems. Unfortunately, I can't figure out the correct regex.

My primary stumbling block is the number of periods varies drastically, and I'm not sure how to write a regex when the number of items will vary randomly throughout the string. I've found as many as 8 periods in one of these email addresses, totally random where in the string they'll show up.

It'd be easy if I could just strip out all periods but I can't because I need the `@gmail.com` to stay untouched. Additionally this regex should only match on @gmail.com addresses and ignore other email providers.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [positive lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to match all the dots which are present before to the `@gmail.com`

```
\.(?=.*?@gmail\.com)
```

Then replace the matched dots with an empty string.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/gX5qF3/3)

Answer (score 18):

There's another trick with gmail addresses: Any text after a `+` character is ignored, so e.g. `foo@gmail.com` and `foo+bar@gmail.com` are effectively the same address.

You can use this pattern to remove all text after a `+` character, as well as all dots (shamelessly based on Raj's pattern, please don't hate me):

```
(?:\.|\+.*)(?=.*?@gmail\.com)
```

(replace with the empty string)

[regex101 demo.](https://regex101.com/r/yD2hI7/2)

Comment: Thanks! Upvoted. I accepted Raj's though because he provided the correct answer originally and yours was based on it. 

I know the `+` trick exists, but I haven't seen spammers use it much--I suspect many forum/blog apps don't all `+`'s in their email validation schemes, despite it being technically allowed by the RFC (afaik).

Comment: @Rawing, but op is not asking for removing text from the plus sign. Well, new to know about `+` sign in email.

Comment: Strike my earlier comment. Just discovered several hundred spammers using the '+' trick in their gmail address. Thanks again for this!